# biblatex multiple set of author with the option subentry

Tags: biblatex, biber, mcite

I notice something strange when I use `biblatex` with a set of author through the command `\mcite` with the option `subentry` in order to distinguish the different authors in the set. If I call several time a set, the subentry is not working well for the first call: I get only a) and not a), b) ...

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{hyperref}   


\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,      
    bibstyle=numeric,       
    mcite=true,             
    subentry,               
    backend=biber           
    ]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{./biblio.bib}


\begin{document}        
    This is some nice text I want to cite as a set\mcite{set1,*Boncella1984,*Tilley1982}.

    Another set cite\mcite{set2,*Tilley1982,*Boncella1984}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the bib file `biblio.bib`:

```
@article{Boncella1984,
author = {Boncella, James M. and Andersen, Richard A.},
journal = {Inorg. Chem.},
pages = {432--437},
volume = {23},
year = {1984}
}

@article{Tilley1982,
author = {Tilley, T. Don and Andersen, Richard},
journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
pages = {1772--1774},
volume = {104},
year = {1982}
}
```

Comment: Mhh yes, this looks like a bug. I'll probably open a bug report at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues once I have investigated this more thoroughly. Even though I would say this is a bug I should warn you that using the same entry in multiple sets could cause weird or undesirable output in some places (if you decide to `\cite{Tilley1982}` what output would you expect?).

Comment: In some previous code, by citing `\cite{Tilley1982}`, I got a subentry like [2a], which is fine for me. But I understand your purpose, why it should not be an other subentry from the first set like [1b] or even a new entry. Maybe a command with options could help us to determine which one should be chose.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This could be considered a bug in `biblatex` and was reported as such in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/815, the fix in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/822 has been merged and is present in `biblatex` 3.12
>
> If you are having this problem, consider updating your TeX distribution. The answer below is left for historic interest and background information.

The problem only surfaces if a child entry is used in several different (parent) sets (in different positions). In order for `\cite{<child>}` (e.g. `\cite{Boncella1984}` in your example, `\cite{sigfridsson}` below) to work properly, the entry needs to be assigned the subentry information when the `.bbl` is read. If one entry belongs to several sets, the last set to be processed wins (hence `\cite{Boncella1984}`/`\cite{sigfridsson}` comes out as [2b] and not [1a] in citations). It is a priori not clear what *should* happen in cases like this, so I guess 'the last set wins' is an OKish rule. In the bibliography, however, it is always clear to which set a child belongs and there the number should be taken from the current set.

That is what https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/822 implements by simply stepping up a counter when the set entry is processed in the bibliography.

Until a version with the fix is released you can use the following workaround

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage[style=numeric,
    mcite=true,
    subentry,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcount\blx@entrysetcounter

\def\blx@entryset#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@imc@clearlist{pageref}%
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \global\blx@entrysetcounter\@ne
     \edef\abx@field@entrysetcount{\the\blx@entrysetcounter}%
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglangbib
     \blx@begunit
     \blx@anchor
     \blx@entryset@precode
     \blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}%
     \blx@entryset@postcode
     \blx@endunit
     \blx@endlangbib
     \endgroup}
    {}%
  \let\do\blx@entryset@i}

\def\blx@entryset@i#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \global\advance\blx@entrysetcounter\@ne
     \edef\abx@field@entrysetcount{\the\blx@entrysetcounter}%
     \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglangbib
     \blx@begunit
     \blx@anchor
     \blx@entryset@precode
     \blx@driver{\blx@imc@thefield{entrytype}}%
     \blx@entryset@postcode
     \blx@endunit
     \blx@endlangbib
     \endgroup}
    {\blx@nounit}}

\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}        
  This is some nice text I want to cite as a set\mcite{set1,*sigfridsson,*worman}.
  \cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{worman}

  Another set cite\mcite{set2,*worman,*sigfridsson}.
  \cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{worman}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]